# Seeking source code for Balls (Atari ST/STOS game)

Tags: gaming, atari-st

I'm seeking the source code for an old Atari ST game [STFBalls](http://www.atarimania.com/game-atari-st-balls_31189.html)<sup>1</sup> a.k.a STBalls a.k.a. Balls which was released as shareware back in the early '90s.  According to the author, anyone making a shareware donation would get a copy of the game's STOS Basic source code.  Does anyone know where the source code might be found today, know how to contact the author (Simon Carter), or have a copy of it lying around?

If I can find a copy of the source code I'd like to try porting it to something more modern (probably HTML/Javascript).  The levels and graphics would be pretty easy to extract from the binary version; determining the behavior of the various "widgets" in the game would need either the source code, a disassembler, or playing the game all the way through ;^).<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>The binary, levels file, and readme are available as a floppy disk image on the linked site; the source code is not.

<sup>2</sup> Reverse engineering by editing the levels file might also work but only if all of the widget behavior is deterministic and not context-dependent.

Screenshots:

[image: Title screen]
[image: Level 1]

Comment: You can use emulator to run the game. What is the purpose of endeavour?

Comment: Well, I'd like to run it on my phone for one.  I've tried it under an emulator there and it was too wonky to be usable.  Plus would be fun to port and might even be a bit of challenge.

Comment: This: https://twitter.com/bbbscarter "Brainfarts from an ageing games coder" would be high probability hit. Google search rules :)

Comment: I think that's him.  Maybe he still has the code.  Thanks!

Comment: Your Google skills are better than mine.  I haven't been able to find anything with it since they made it "easy to use" by "intelligently" telling me what I was really searching for.  That and taking away all the boolean query options.  Bring back lycos.cmu.edu!

Comment: Just one word of caution. Shareware *doesn't* mean free-for-all, porting is not necessarily allowed, even if you paid. It was a way to allow you to run something before comitting to payment but the right to create derivative works are not necessarily part of that. The copyright will *still* be retained by the author. So any avenue that doesn't explicitly license you to create derivatives (and this can only come from the copyright holder) will not be kosher (so to speak).

Comment: FWIW, I see nothing in the licence (http://www.atarimania.com/game-atari-st-balls_31189.html) that allows for the creation of derivatives. The bit about electrodes and various body parts is concerening, but ultimately toothless since there's no talk of actually applying current to said electrodes :-)

Comment: Of course, you *may* be able to get permission from the author, it's just that I spent a *lot* of time working at a certain large organisation (that takes IP seriously), in close proximity to the legal bods, so I know how it works. However, I'm *not* a lawyer, and especially not *your* lawyer, so feel free to ignore my non-advice, though at your peril :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I am aware of the law regarding derivative works, etc.  My main interest is for personal use and reüsing graphics, levels, etc. for my own use (without redistribution) falls under "first sale" (in the US).  Anything beyond that would be up the original author; something like AGPL3 or PD would be needed to allow redistribution (at least of the levels and graphics).  As for having paid the shareware fee, I don't recall that particular person coming by my house and hooking up electrodes so I suppose I must have paid back in the day ;^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per an anonymous commenter, the author (Simon Carter) appears to be on Twitter as [`@bbbscarter`](https://twitter.com/bbbscarter) with a blog at [bbbscarter.wordpress.com](https://bbbscarter.wordpress.com/)  The person who did the graphics (Dene Carter) also appears to be on Twitter as [`@Fluttermind`](https://twitter.com/Fluttermind) with a website at [www.fluttermind.com](http://www.fluttermind.com/)

Comment: Yeah, except he never responded to my postings :(

Comment: I've been too busy to ask myself (I'm not on twitter)